# Anular css en una parte de la pagina

Tags: html5, css3

Amigos!, tengo una duda y es la siguiente.

en el html de mi página tengo relacionado bootstrap de la forma tipica, en el head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

y debajo del body los js

mi pregunta es, necesito relacionar en un div especifico un cdn de otro complemento, sin embargo al hacerlo altero todo el codigo siguiente, entonces, ¿Cómo puedo anular la relacion de bootstrap solo en un sector especifico de la pagina, o para hacerlo mas sencillo, como puedo añadir mi cdn solo en un div especifico sin alterar lo demas?

Comment: La única manera que se me ocurre es poniendo esa parte dentro de un **<iframe>** con otro archivo html que incluya la librería. Pero habría que ver si funciona, y dudo que sea una buena práctica.

Comment: si quieres usar bootstrap en un solo div no tiene mucho sentido cargar toda la librería, sería mejor que buscaras qué estilos en concreto necesitas y copiarlos y pegarlos en tu hoja de estilos.

Answer (score 1):

No es facil. Pero si lo aprendes tu codigo sera mucho mas ordenado, sobretodo en proyectos grandes.

Tienes que utilizar tecnologia adicional para encapsular partes, para que funcionan por separado. Yo utilizo [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/). Ya te aviso que esta mas bien enfocado en empresas grandes, asi que aún que hay bastante gente que lo utilizan, tambien hay bastante gente que no saben ni lo que es.

Entonces lo que aprenderas con Polymer, es poder encapsular todo. CSS, librerias, HTML, JS, etc. Y luego estas partes iras incluyendo dentro de la pagina web. Seran como bloques bastante simples, pero con un mundo detras.

Otra forma que te comentan con iframe, es una manera de hacer lo bastante facil, pero luego te vendra el castigo cuando lo empezaras usar en diferentes dispostivos. Los iframes en los mobiles pueden comportarse bastante mal.